# bash: ./configure: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell, autotools

I am experimenting with Linux, and my work uses CentOS 6.5, so I am using that at home.  I am following a tutorial, followed it closely I believe, yet I am hitting an error like the one mentioned in the topic.  The tutorial is on how to setup a webserver.  Things are going as shown in the tutorial until this error:

```
bash: ./configure: no such file or directory
```

This is the command section I am currently stuck at.  I did install the current suphp 0.7.2 vs the prescribed 0.7.1 assuming that would not cause troubles.  If it is the cause, please let me know.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://suphp.org/download/suphp-0.7.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz suphp-0.7.2.tar.gz
cd suphp-0.7.2/
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-apache-user=apache --with-setid-mode=owner --with-php=/usr/bin/php-cgi --with-logfile=/var/log/httpd/suphp_log --enable-SUPHP_USE_USERGROUP=yes
***never got past this point, as I errored at the last command**
make
make install
```

[Tutorial link](https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-6.5-apache2-mysql-php-pureftpd-postfix-dovecot-and-ispconfig3)

Comment: What's the output of ls -la in that directory? It seems that the configure file is not present.

Comment: Works for me as given. Please check that you can run `/bin/sh`, since that's what the `./configure` script expects to run it.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the suggestion, I corrected the code with the code I typed.
 same screenshot shows the output of when I type /bin/sh  http://prntscr.com/8gpo3f

Comment: @NathanV Here is that output of that directory, and config seems to be there, right?  http://prntscr.com/8gpo3f

Comment: Please provide the (single line plus header) output of the `mount` command that explicitly references either `/tmp` or `/`. Ideally it would be `/tmp` but if there isn't one then please provide the line for `/`. What I'm now expecting to see is a mount point for `/tmp` that includes the `noexec` parameter.

Comment: @roaima thanks for the replies.  I did a mount command, here is the output.  I don't see any reference to /tmp, is that what you were looking for?  http://prntscr.com/8gpu52

Comment: @roaima to your suggestion to do just a ./configure, this is the odd reply.  What does it mean?
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in config "."/config  
http://prntscr.com/8gpzls

Comment: @roaima You have been so much help, thanks for helping me though this btw.  Now it seems you are right, configure is replying, but with different error.  http://prntscr.com/8gq343

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29175/discussion-between-roaima-and-eric).

Comment: Roaima and I concluded this is a quirk that should not be happening.  Possibly due to my use of 0.7.2 vs documented 0.7.1.  I will reattempt the build using the 0.7.1 - or abandon the project and attempt a different exercise using CentOS 6.5.  Followup tomorrow with whether or not the 0.7.1 was successful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Having had a look at the contents of `suphp-0.7.2.tar.gz`, it seems as if the error is due to a badly built distribution.  There are build tools missing in the `config` subfolder.

You have little choice other than recreating the `configure` script using the GNU autotools.

1. Install `automake` and `autoconf` on your Unix.
2. Run `autoreconf -i` in the `suphp-0.7.2` folder.

This will cause the GNU autotools to investigate the distribution files and rebuild any `Makefile.in` that is out of date as well as recreate the `configure` script and install the missing build tools in the `config` directory.

If that all goes well, you're then set to start again at `./configure`.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following with in the unzipped folder

```
autoreconf -i
```

and then running

```
./configure
```

worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question and the last response was last year...

This might help someone else.  I have run into this issue when downloading source packages that were not configured properly.

Normally if you get this error you can attempt the following:

./buildconf

This should generate the configure file that is missing.

Projects that are checked out normally require conf to be run on it, buildconf / autoconf.  When you download a source archive, it normally has these commands run on it already.

Comment: I believe that `buildconf` is something from the PHP distro.  Also, if you have that script inside your root directory (`/`) you probably have problems enough.

Comment: It is not in the root, it is with the application you are trying to build. It is generated by the autoconf / autobuild tools.  It is not in "/" it is run with "./buildconf" and my period was stripped off by some formatting.  If you have built anything in C you will know this.

Comment: I do not believe that building things in C makes one good at guessing where missing characters are, heh.  That said there was quite a while since the last time I did build anything all the way down from autoconf, so i may have missed a file alright.  Googling it appears to say that it was a file that was part of autoconf a long while back - i'd guess it was the original name of the `autoreconf` script.  Don't think OP will be able to download and build an old enough version of autoconf and automake to make use of it.

Comment: Only reason I say that is because I build everyday in linux command line using gcc / cpp, for customers requesting custom builds.  Normally you don't have to use autoconf, packages you download normally have had everything run on it already.  However, if you check out a c / cpp project from source, you are normally required to build.  You should be able to get any version of make/conf from the linux archives.  I have a copy of the old repo if anyone needs it.