# libsocketcan ./configure: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, configure

I want to install [libsocketcan](https://git.pengutronix.de/cgit/tools/libsocketcan) from source on my raspberry pi. I already installed libsocketcan on my
Ubunutu VM successfully by following the instructions of the INSTALL file. Unfortunately the first step of the installation is is not working on the raspberry pi. The first step of the installation is to cd into the directory and to run **./configure** but when i do this i get ./configure: No such file or directory. What can i do in this situation? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is there a `autogen.sh` file? you may need to run that first, to generate the `configure` script

Comment: @steeldriver yes there is an autogen.sh file.

Comment: You also need libtool

Comment: @jsbillings you are right. I just found it out the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got `./configure` to work and could install libsocketcan on the raspberry pi. I did the following:

First i found this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229887/bash-configure-no-such-file-or-directory). The answers suggested to install `autoconf` and `automake` and to run `autoreconf -i`. After i did this i could run `./configure` atleast but i got the following error:

```
pi@RPI4:~/Repositorys/libsocketcan-0.0.12 $ ./configure
checking build system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking host system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
./configure: line 3175: syntax error near unexpected token `win32-dll'
./configure: line 3175: `LT_INIT(win32-dll)'
```

I ran the `autoreconf -i` again and i suddendly got this different output:

```
src/GNUmakefile.am:1: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
src/GNUmakefile.am:1:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
src/GNUmakefile.am:1:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
src/GNUmakefile.am:1:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
src/GNUmakefile.am:1:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

A quick search of the error suggested to [install libtool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229887/bash-configure-no-such-file-or-directory) with `sudo apt-get install libtool`. I did this and ran `autoreconf -i` again. After this the ./configure finally worked.